# Errno 111: Connect call failed ('172.18.0.4', 5672)

Tags: docker, docker-compose, rabbitmq

I have 2 services in my microservice application, Post and Notification. I am using Rabbitmq to pass message from Post to Notification. When I am running these two services on localhost, they work perfectly. Adding post successfully passes message to Notification.

But when I try to run these two services using docker-compose, there are some bugs. While adding post, suspicious error message is not shown.

```
test1-rabbitmq-1              | 2023-10-04 16:31:00.876622+00:00 [info] <0.761.0> accepting AMQP connection <0.761.0> (172.18.0.8:50708 -> 172.18.0.4:5672)
test1-rabbitmq-1              | 2023-10-04 16:31:01.010876+00:00 [info] <0.761.0> connection <0.761.0> (172.18.0.8:50708 -> 172.18.0.4:5672): user 'admin' authenticated and granted access to vhost '/'
test1-post-service-1          | INFO:     172.18.0.1:47970 - "POST /post HTTP/1.1" 200 OK
test1-rabbitmq-1              | 2023-10-04 16:31:01.109388+00:00 [info] <0.761.0> closing AMQP connection <0.761.0> (172.18.0.8:50708 -> 172.18.0.4:5672, vhost: '/', user: 'admin')
```

However no message is passed to Notification service at all, but this error message is shown:

```
test1-notification-service-1  | [Errno 111] Connect call failed ('172.18.0.4', 5672)
```

Post service:

```
rabbitmq_host = "rabbitmq"
rabbitmq_port = 5672 
rabbitmq_user = "admin"  
rabbitmq_password = "admin123"  

posting=APIRouter()
@posting.post("/post")
async def add_post(post:NewPost):
    try:
        result = post_db['post'].insert_one({
            "username": post.username,
            "texts": post.texts
        })
        post_id = result.inserted_id

        notification_data = {
            "username": post.username,
            "postId": str(post_id)
        }

        connection = pika.BlockingConnection(
            pika.ConnectionParameters(
                host=rabbitmq_host,
                port=rabbitmq_port,
                credentials=pika.credentials.PlainCredentials(
                    username=rabbitmq_user,
                    password=rabbitmq_password,
                ),
            )
        )
        channel=connection.channel()
        channel.exchange_declare(
            exchange="post",
            exchange_type="direct"
        )
        channel.basic_publish(
            exchange='post',
            routing_key='post.notify',
            body=json.dumps(notification_data)
        )
        connection.close()
    except Exception as error:
        print(error)
```

Notification service:

```
rabbitmq_host = "rabbitmq"
rabbitmq_port = 5672 
rabbitmq_user = "admin"  
rabbitmq_password = "admin123"  

notification=APIRouter()
@notification.on_event('startup')
async def startup_event():
    try:
        connection = await aio_pika.connect_robust(
            host=rabbitmq_host,
            port=rabbitmq_port,
            login=rabbitmq_user,
            password=rabbitmq_password,
        )

        channel = await connection.channel()
        channel.exchange_declare(
                exchange="post",
                exchange_type="direct"
        )
        queue = await channel.declare_queue('post_notify')
        await queue.bind('post', 'post.notify')
        await queue.consume(add_notification)
        print("Consuming messages...")

    except Exception as error:
        print(error)
async def add_notification(message: aio_pika.IncomingMessage):
    try:
        notification = json.loads(message.body)
        await message.ack()
        notification_db['notification'].insert_one(notification)
        print("notification added!")

    except Exception as error:
        print(error)
        raise HTTPException(status_code=500, detail="Internal server error")
```

My docker-compose file is:

```
version: '3'
services:
  post-service:
    build:
      context: ./Post  # Updated build context path
    command: uvicorn main:app --reload --host 0.0.0.0 --port 8000
    ports:
      - "8001:8000"
    networks:
      - mynetwork
    depends_on:
      - mongodb
      - rabbitmq
    
  notification-service:
    build:
      context: ./Notification  # Updated build context path
    command: uvicorn main:app --reload --host 0.0.0.0 --port 8000
    ports:
      - "8002:8000"
    networks:
      - mynetwork
    depends_on:
      - mongodb
      - rabbitmq
    
  
  rabbitmq:
    image: "rabbitmq:3-management"
    ports:
      - "5672:5672"  
      - "15672:15672"  
    env_file:
      - rabbitmq.env #same configuration as Post and Notification
    networks:
      - mynetwork
  mongodb:
    image: mongo:4.4.24
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
    networks:
      - mynetwork
networks:
  mynetwork:
```

I have tried solutions from other similar problems. I am quite new to rabbitmq. It would be greatly helpful if someone help me figuring out what I am doing wrong. If additional information is needed, please let me know.

Comment: The IP addresses in those error messages don't line up.  The first logs seem to be using a 192.168.16.0/24 network, but the second log is trying to connect to 172.28.0.3.  How have you configured the notification service to talk to RabbitMQ?

Comment: @David Maze I ran the docker-compose 2 times. Each time the similar error. As I am not using localhost anymore, I think my device's IP address is being used. Also i have used the same configuration as Post service.

Comment: I have updated my question. As I had ran the docker-compose twice, there were some inconsistency regarding connection address.